# How to delete data with PIG and Cassandra CqlStorage

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig, cql3

I am trying to delete data Cassandra using Pig. The documentation only indicates "update statement": http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/about_pig. Perhaps the only way is to create a "Pig UDF" to remove that data.

**Schema**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_test WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':2};
CREATE TABLE user (name text,last_name text,adress text,PRIMARY KEY (name));
INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, adress) VALUES ('albert','griffith', 'street example1');
INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, adress) VALUES ('adam','garcia', 'street example2');
```

**Script Pig**

```
users = LOAD 'cql://keyspace_test/user' USING CqlStorage();
user = filter users by name == 'adam';
data_to_delete = FOREACH user GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('name',name)),() ;
STORE data_to_delete INTO 'cql://keyspace_test/user?output_query=DELETE+FROM+keyspace_test.user' USING CqlStorage;
```

**Result**

Although, indicating that everything has gone right, it has not deleted the cassandra data:

Input(s):

```
Successfully read 2 records from: "cql://keyspace_test/user"
```

Output(s):

```
Successfully stored 1 records in: "cql://keyspace_test/user?output_query=DELETE+FROM+keyspace_test.user"
```

Counters:

```
Total records written : 1
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

Comment: did you find any answer for this? or you are removing in pig UDF?